# Migrating WCF service to CoreWCF, Client couldn't communicate with Hosted Service

Tags: wcf, .net-7.0, duplex-channel, corewcf

I'm working on migrating WCF services to CoreWCF. In the service side I can able to host the service by using WebApplicationBuilder (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder).

But the client side when I'm trying to connect with service getting following error,

"System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.'"

Please help me to fix this error.

Note: simple CoreWCF service and client is working fine. but with the callback and duplexchannel its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **"Service Trace Viewer Tool"** to track and find out the problem before solving it.
I think the documentation below is helpful to you:
[Service Trace Viewer Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe?redirectedfrom=MSDN)